# Making unresponsive website responsive a easily as possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have made a terrible error. I have built an entire website without making it responsive. Is there any quick easy way to make the whole site responsive so when in landscape mode it all looks exactly like my website on a desktop computer? I am a designer for print but not great with websites as you can see but I really do not want to start the whole site again.

Maybe a media query to with ratios? so the whole site looks the same just smaller and fits on the screen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rebuild it in a framework like Hoisin.css, you just need to convert your design into columns, IMO that would be the best and quickest way to fix your issue

Comment: Have a look at: http://speckyboy.com/2014/04/24/make-any-website-responsive/ - though quick and easy will depend entirely on the size of your site and choices you have made already.

Answer (score 3):

Try using CSS @media Rule, and specify your styles accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at plugins that help you do it. RestiveJS is an example.

http://restivejs.com

Answer (score 0):

For the future: the easiest way to implement the @media rules is the usage of `em` instead of pixel.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

> **em** Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the
>   size of the current font)

if you then want your website to adjust to your screensize, simply use

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) { // ipad width in portrait 
    body {font-size: 0.7em}
}
```

everything is 30% smaller on devices with a screen width smaller than 769px then if you used `em` instead of `px`